# How do I move my windows 10 license to a new PC, when I can't access the old one?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I bought a Windows 10 Home license a few years ago. Recently my current PC broke and instead of fixing it I'm considering building a new one altogether. Is there an easy way to move my windows to the new one (which will not come with any system preinstalled), when i don't have access to my broken computer?

Comment: As long as it is a full retail version then if you still have the box then it should have the product code in it, if you bought it online then you should have the code in an email. Otherwise you might be able to find it in the linked Microsoft account. If you bought an OEM licence then it does with the machine it was installed on and cannot be transferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you purchased a retail copy of Windows 10 Home, you would have received a product key with it (either via email or in the physical packaging).  Windows licenses sold through retail channels are eligible to be moved from one PC to another.  All you need to do is activate the key on the new computer.  It doesn't matter that you've activated it already, as long as it was a sufficient time ago (Microsoft's activation servers "forget" activated keys after a certain length of time).

If you do not have the product key, then you are possibly out of luck here, unless you purchased it directly from Microsoft and you still have the confirmation email you received (which *should* have the product key in it already). I have no idea what their process would be to get a new key issued (if it's even possible).  Aside from that, you will need access to the old computer period.  There is no other way without resorting to piracy.

Comment: Thanks, do you know approximately how much time has to pass before they "forget" a key? I do still have it, and I've used it for the previous PC around 3-4 years ago, so I would assume I'm good to go?

Comment: Last I knew it was ~6 months but that was a long time ago. Even if they've gotten more strict about it though, I'd think 3-4 years would be plenty of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your purchased computer almost certainly (90% or more) came with an OEM Windows license. Then (as noted above) that license can not be transferred to a new computer.

So consider the cost of purchasing a new Windows license (about $100) and determine whether it remains in your best interest to make your own computer, or purchase a decent model computer that comes with another OEM license.